# How to replace slashes with hyphens and change the place of the year and the day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a birthday string field in this format:

```
17/06/1989
```

How Can I convert it to this format using hyphens:

```
1989-06-17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using date parsing:

```
Date.parse("17/06/1989").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Or with a regex substitution:

```
"17/06/1989".gsub(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, '\3-\2-\1')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
"17/06/1989".to_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```